# One stop solution to stay up to date with new releases in SF & F

Tags: publishing

I don't have a bookstore nearby that carries a good selection of SF & F, so I do all my reading shopping online. Problem is, I don't know what there is to buy.

**Where do you guys find out about recently published novels in Science Fiction and Fantasy?**

I'm not interested in reviews, news on which writer might write what, which bookstore has closed, conventions etc., just a simple list of everything that is newly available in bookstores.

Comment: To those who voted to close: No doubt you are the People, and wisdom will die with you. But doesn't it seem odd, for a "request for a list of works or recommendations", that the accepted answer (with comment "this is exactly what I want") is a one-liner, which does not recommend, list, or mention any works at all? You **do** understand the difference between a "list question" and asking whether a list exists, don't you?

Comment: @user14111 Sure, they probably should have gone with a custom close reason, but that doesn't make the question appropriate. The ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) section of the help centre specifically mentions that questions where "every answer is equally valid" are considered unsuitable for the StackExchange format.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The guy wanted to know where there's a site that lists all new releases in SF&F. You think this question has a bunch of equally valid answers. I'm inclined to doubt that, hence my vote to reopen. As a newbie, I'm not sure what's the significance of closing a question after it has already been definitively answered. I guess we've got to keep this site safe for *real* questions like "does Harry Potter wear boxers or briefs?".

Comment: If you go over to Stackoverflow, you will find many programming questions where each answer is a valid, working solution. None of them get closed.

Comment: @what This isn't StackOverflow.  Nor is it Movies & TV, which has their own solution to the same problem.  Every site has its own meta site, in which users debate over what works and what doesn't.  On SciFi.SE, we've learned over time that questions which are open to what we call "me, too!" answers just don't work; they continue accumulating new answers long after one has been accepted, making any one single posted answer incomplete (because none of them can include all the "me, too!" answers).  That is why SciFi.SE doesn't accept so-called "list" questions.

Comment: @what Additionally, inviting discussion isn't accepted on _any_ StackExchange site, as they're all oriented towards questions & answers.  "Primarily opinion-based" is a _second_ close reason that IMO applies to this question.  [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley), on the other hand, is made for discussion.

Comment: Related [Meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3144/1027).

Comment: @Izkata Wow, look at all the "me, too!" answers this question is getting! No, wait. No more answers have been forthcoming since the correct answer was posted and accepted. Since list questions lead to "me, too!" answers, I guess that proves that this wasn't a list question, hmm?

Comment: @Izkata How is this question "primarily opinion-based"? How is it "opinion-based" at all? The fact that ISFDB maintains a list of virtually all newly released science fiction and fantasy book in English seems to be about as much a matter of opinion as "Fargo is the capital of North Dakota".

Comment: @Izkata This question is a good example of an opinion-free factual question. An "opinion-based" question would be one like "in which order should I start watching Star Trek movies and TV series."

Comment: @user14111 `Where do you guys find out about...` is practically the definition of "opinion-based", and why I brought up "inviting discussion" in the prior comment.  I go to physical bookstores, for example.

Comment: Folks, take it to chat or the above-linked Meta post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the list of [Selected Upcoming Books](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi) (scroll down) and the list of [All Forthcoming Books](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/fc.cgi) at the ISFDB.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I'd strongly recommend using [goodreads](http://goodreads.com/). I am logging all books I've read there for several reasons:

- They send out a 'new books from authors you've read' newsletter every month. In the beginning that's not that much, but last month I found four new books I want to read with that newsletter alone.
- They've also got a recommendation-function, which is based on what you've read so far and how much you liked it (and it's sorted by genre too).
- You can even 'become a fan' of your favourite authors, so you get updated on their stuff. (This is like facebook's 'like' essentially)

I'm not saying you won't miss any books anymore, but I've stumbled across so much awesome books there that it's become my single source for information on new books.

Comment: You've forgotten to mention that you can also give and recieve recommendations between friends on Goodreads. I find this just as invaluable as the monthly newsletter. It's helpful to have friends with the same taste as you though :P

Comment: +1 that's nice, I didn't know this site. I'll certainly take a look at it, but actually I don't want recommendations, because I have often found books boring that others recommended, and vice versa. I'm a bit of a non-mainstream reader and have a hard time finding things I like, which is why I want to see everything and not miss the books in the small publishing houses and other "hidden gems". But then maybe there is someone with a similar taste on goodreads, so I will definitely try it.

Comment: @RobertEnglish: I heavily dislike social networking, so I don't use those features that much. But you're right, if you're into that, it might be very helpful. This might be especially useful, if one is a non-mainstream reader, given one finds someone with similar taste.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an advanced search on amazon.com and search by publication date, it may not give you everything but it should be close enough.  Previewing however poses a problem due to copyright issues, if a specific author has a website they may make a few chapters of some of their work available or even complete books (like through the Baen free library)

Comment: Thank you. I took out the preview part of my question. I will post that as a separate question. I'm not really happy with that function on Amazon, though, because it seems to me that there is too included in their "list" that I don't want, e.g. reprints of older books. But I'll take a look at it again and compare it to the other solutions. +1 for your help.